# Determining charging voltage under load

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, charging, lithium

I'm building a backup system for some computer hardware which is roughly a constant 20W of power at ~48V. I've built a 13S5P Li-Ion pack from the following [cells](https://www.orbtronic.com/content/samsung-35e-datasheet-inr18650-35e.pdf). I'm experimenting with different charging voltages at the moment but I'm having a hard time charging the batteries under load.

I've set the [charger](https://www.tyconsystems.com/documentation/Spec%20Sheets/TPDIN-SC48-20%20%20200W%20Solar%20Controller%20with%20Monitor%20and%20Gigabit%20PoE%20Switch%20Spec%20Sheet.pdf) to float at 4.2V/cell with the load connected. After fully charging, I'll disconnect the [Power Supply](https://www.belfuse.com/product/part-details?partn=LDC480-72P), and the voltage drops immediately to ~3.2V/cell.

However, If I disconnect the load while charging, the batteries will stay at 4.2V/cell when disconnecting the Power Supply.

Do I need to charge the batteries at a higher voltage than 4.2V/cell? Do I need a better charger or power supply? I'm just not sure what I should be looking up to understand my problem better.

Thanks!